# Obtener datos de la base de datos de esta manera, Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase

Como obtengo estos datos que se ven marcado en este ejemplo, en una lista.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente este codigo, pero nada.

String cuswtId = String.valueOf(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Customers")

¿Alguna forma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas son las keys de los nodos, con este código leerías todos los nodos que cuelgan de customers, y de esos nodos te quedas con las keys.

```java
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Customers");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot nodo : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = nodo.getKey(); //estos son los valores que buscas
            Log.d("TAG", key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```